# How to fetch first form data and set that data in second form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have models `Offer` & `OfferItem` as below and I need to create an `Offer` and `OfferItem` at same template page. My problem is I want to save `offer_form` first then set saved offer record as related on `itemOffer` field then save `offeritem_form` how can I do it? Or may be my models and logic is completely wrong, if so is there any other way to do it?

*I exclude **HStoreField**, cuz I will need to save multiple `OfferItem`s at same page (may be I am wrong again I don't know)

Here is my models etc.

Models;

```
class Offer(models.Model):

    offerCreate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    offerOwner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offerNumber = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    offerCondi = models.TextField()
    offerTotal = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.offerNumber

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Offer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Offers'

class OfferItem(models.Model):

    itemOffer = models.ForeignKey('sales.Offer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemName = models.CharField(max_length = 150,null=True)
    itemProduct = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemLeadtime = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    itemCost = models.FloatField()
    itemPrice = models.FloatField()
    itemCurrency = models.ForeignKey('products.Currency', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemQuantity = models.IntegerField()
    itemOfferprice = models.FloatField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.itemName

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = 'OfferItem'
        verbose_name_plural = 'OfferItems'
```

View;

```
def createofferView(request):
    offer_form = CreateOfferForm(request.POST or None)
    offeritem_form = CreateOfferItemForm(request.POST or None)
    if offer_form.is_valid() and offeritem_form.is_valid():
        offer_form.save()
        offeritem_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Success!')
        return redirect('offers')

    return render(request, 'sales/createoffer.html',{'offer_form':offer_form,'offeritem_form':offeritem_form})
```

Comment: just assign the result of `save()` to a variable: `offer = offer_form.save(); item = offeritem_form.save(commit=False); item.offer = offer; item.save()`. Look at the [docs for save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

Comment: @dirkgroten works perfectly, just fixed `item.offer = offer` to `item.itemOffer = offer` thats all please add this as an answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your field naming conventions are bad. If the model is `Offer`, why prefix all fields with `offer` (same with `OfferItem`)? It makes for difficult-to-read code: `item.itemOffer`, `offer.offerNumber` isn't easy to read, what is an `itemOffer` or a `offerNumber`? I recommend `item.offer` and `offer.number` etc... Much clearer.

Comment: Noted @dirkgroten, to be honest I am new at this and learning more and more. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ModelForm.save()` method returns the instance that was saved. In addition, you can `save(commit=False)` to create the instance without committing (saving) it to the database. This allows you to do this:

```
offer = offer_form.save()
item = offeritem_form.save(commit=False)  # we don't commit yet, because we need to assign the offer first
item.itemOffer = offer
item.save()
```

This is basically what the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) tell you about `ModelForm.save()`. You should use the docs as much as you can, they contain a lot of examples that answer most of your questions.

Note: It is good practice in python to try to be as concise as possible (but also as clear as possible). Your code should read like English sentences. `item.itemOffer = offer` is not good English. `item.offer = offer` makes more sense grammatically. Name your fields accordingly, don't prefix them all with `item` or `offer` since they are already used in the context of an `OfferItem` of `Offer` anyway.